# django static files error 404 - aws lightsail

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, django-staticfiles, amazon-lightsail

I followed amazon docs on how to [Deploy A Django Project](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/)

My settings.py

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['X.XXX.XXX.XXX']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass'
    }
}

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cms/static')
]
```

I used `'Host': 'localhost'` because `'HOST': '/opt/bitnami/postgresql/',` gives me this error which I have asked a question about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860073/could-not-connect-to-postgresql-server-django-lightsail):

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/opt/bitnami/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

and `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` works fine just like in my laptop.

I added static root in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
    .
    .
    
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

under `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts` I created two files:

`cms-http-vhost.conf`  :

```
<IfDefine !IS_CMS_LOADED>
  Define IS_CMS_LOADED
  WSGIDaemonProcess cms python-home=/home/bitnami/py37-venv/ python-path=/home/bitnami/project/cms
</IfDefine>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
  ServerAlias *
  WSGIProcessGroup cms
  Alias /robots.txt /home/bitnami/project/cms/static/robots.txt
  Alias /static/ /home/bitnami/project/cms/static/
  <Directory /home/bitnami/project/cms/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/bitnami/project/cms/cms/wsgi.py
  <Directory /home/project/cms/cms>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and `cms-https-vhost.conf`:

```
<IfDefine !IS_CMS_LOADED>
  Define IS_CMS_LOADED
  WSGIDaemonProcess cms python-home=/home/bitnami/py37-venv/ python-path=/home/bitnami/project/cms
</IfDefine>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
  ServerAlias *
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key"
  WSGIProcessGroup APPNAME
  Alias /robots.txt /home/bitnami/project/cms/static/robots.txt
  Alias /static/ /home/project/cms/static/
  <Directory /home/project/cms/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/project/cms/cms/wsgi.py
  <Directory /home/project/cms/cms>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I run the project with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and I get 404 error for every stataic file in the terminal:

```
"GET /static/img/showcase.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

If I change debug mode to `True` every static file would load correctly.

I also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187103/static-files-not-being-served-on-aws-lightsail), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993463/serving-static-files-on-aws-django-application), but they didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer in [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

In `urls.py` I added this line:

```
from django.views.static import serve
```

add those two urls in urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), 
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

and both static and media files were accesible when DEBUG=FALSE.